# How to access logs in Azure Service Fabric cluster?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I created App package with guest executable without Visual Studio. ConsoleRedirection was also configured to create logs from apps `stdout` and `errout`. It works on local Service Fabric cluster. And the logs can be located in my file system. But how can I access these logs in Azure cloud?

Update:
As LoekD pointed out the Remote Desktop Protocol can be used to access nodes in service fabric cluster. Admin account name could be located in load balancer's automation script in `virtualMachineProfile` section.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a description [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-deploy-existing-app#check-your-running-application) which explains how to discover where the log files are stored.

You can use RDP to access the machine, which is explained [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-cluster-nodetypes/).

Comment: what about applications deployed on linux nodes

Comment: ssh into individual machines by specifying a port between 3389-3393 (in a 5 node cluster)

Comment: Tl;dr `C:\SFDevCluster\Data\_App\_Node_0`